# Regular expression to return all characters between two strings

Tags: python, regex

How can I design a regular expression that will capture all the characters between 2 strings?
Specifically, from this big string:

`Studies have shown that...[^title=Fish consumption and incidence of stroke: a meta-analysis of cohort studies]... Another experiment demonstrated that... [^title=The second title]`

I want to extract all the characters between `[^title=` and `]`, that is, `Fish consumption and incidence of stroke: a meta-analysis of cohort studies` and `The second title`.

I think I will have to use re.findall(), and that I can start with this: `re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', big_string)`, which will give me all the matches between the square brackets `[ ]`, but I'm not sure how to extend it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> text = "Studies have shown that...[^title=Fish consumption and incidence of stroke: a meta-analysis of cohort studies]... Another experiment demonstrated that... [^title=The second title]"
>>> re.findall(r"\[\^title=(.*?)\]", text)
['Fish consumption and incidence of stroke: a meta-analysis of cohort studies', 'The second title']
```

Here is a breakdown of the regex:

`\[` is an escaped [ character.

`\^` is an escaped ^ character.

`title=` matches title=

`(.*?)` matches any characters, non-greedily, and puts them in a group (for findall to extract). Which means it stops when it finds a...

`\]`, which is an escaped ] character.